# Visa for USA for short-term visiting PhD student

Tags: usa, visa, student-visa

I am a PhD student in Spain and I plan to spend 6 months in the US to work on a research project (non-degree seeking student, not paid by the hosting institution, research stay not required by my institution, but will be *"officially set [you] up as a Research Assistant working for me by just filling out a form"*).

I am awaiting information from HR of the hosting institution but in the meantime I am checking the various requirements. I just read that for the J-1 (short stay), institutional, governmental, business, or agency funding must cover at least 50% of the minimum funding required. I am not sure I'll be asked to apply for the J-1, but this would prevent me from coming there since the available scholarships would cover less than 50%. Is the J-1 the right visa type?

Comment: No.  Granted the circumstances you listed, obtaining a visa to come to the US for this type of purpose is quite difficult.  You might be better off coming on an ESTA, and doing what you can to be able to extend it.